# Boolean expression parse and evaluation in C++

Tags: c++, boolean, expression, expression-evaluation

I need to evaluate simple Boolean functions at run time in C++. The functions are read from a file as strings. Is there any library available that I could use for this?

I looked into [BuDDy](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401847) but sounds like it doesn't parse strings.

Comment: I suppose all these http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram#External_links do their job, but it is up to you to load the data

Answer (score 0):

Use boost library (lexical_cast.hpp)

```
bool a = boost::lexical_cast<bool>("true"); //true
bool b = boost::lexical_cast<bool>("0"); //false
```

Or go here [num_get facet and stringstream conversion to boolean - fails with initialised boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880927/num-get-facet-and-stringstream-conversion-to-boolean-fails-with-initialised-bo)